# Actionbar and Tabs and Viewpager and Fragments and Screenorientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying hard to get this work. I want to have an Actionbar with Tabs and a Viewpager. In the Tabs, there shall be one OR two fragments, depending on the screen orientation.

The one OR two fragments have to be (Sherlock)ListFragments.

This works so far. But there isn't any content in the fragments. Not even onCreate or onCreateView from the first fragment is called.

Here the main Activity:

```
public class tabActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        //mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Advanced"),TitlesFragment.class, null);
    }
```

Followed by the mandatory TabsAdapter. I've made it work with ABS. 
The TitlesFragment:

```
public static class TitlesFragment extends SherlockListFragment 
{
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
        mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if (mDualPane) {

            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

            DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);

            if (details == null)
            {
                details = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    }
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entervalues, container, false);
        Activity mFracmentActivity = super.getSherlockActivity();
        setListAdapter(new SpecListAdapter(mFracmentActivity, Shakespeare.TITLES));

        return mView;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if I take the SpecListAdapter or try to call setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES)); in the onCreate() method from the TitlesFragment.

main.xml (res/layout):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml (res/layout-land):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay. This quite doesn't work. For some reasons, there is a problem with the main.xml. I've made another soulution without a main.xml. Just called setContentView(mViewPager); and than edited the layout file for the list, so that another SherlockListFragment with a seperate layout is loaded, if the device is in landscape mode. There is more XML to write, but it has the desired effect.